# How to enforce a select dropdown choice

Tags: html, forms, pug

I have a PUG template with this code:

```
select#categoryDropdown(name='category', required)
  option(value='none', selected, disabled, hidden) -- Select an option --
  option(value='school') school
  option(value='family') family
```

that generates this form:

```html
<select id="categoryDropdown" name="category" required="">
  <option value="none" selected="" disabled="" hidden="">-- Select an option --</option>
  <option value="school">school</option>
  <option value="family">family</option>
</select>
```

The form allows users to submit without selecting a value. I don't know if the issue is that the `-- Select an option --` option is already selected or if my PUG/Jade syntax is not setting the right fields, e.g. with `required=""` instead of just `required`.

How can I fix the PUG code to force users to choose a no-default field in a select dropdown?

Comment: The value for your first option should be "" (an empty string). "none" is a valid value and the required attribute treats it as such.

Comment: @ArthurBoucher Yes, indeed, thank you! Can you write an answer, and maybe edit the question to reflect the actual problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like

```
select#categoryDropdown(name='category', required)
  option(value='', selected) -- Select an option --
  option(value='school') school
  option(value='family') family
```

"none" is a valid value and the required attribute treats it as such.